Building toolchains for compiling Android kernel on aarch64 host
I am using a free ARM (aarch64) compute instance from Oracle Cloud as a development machine. I would like to compile an Kernel for my Android phone (arm64), but I'm having trouble with selecting the appropriate toolchain.
Google provides Android-specific toolchains, aarch64-linux-android- and arm-linux-androideabi-, but these are primarily distributed for x86_64 hosts.
After a couple of hours of searching the internet, I found mentions that I could use the host (or native) compiler for my system, which happens to be aarch64-linux-gnu- and arm-linux-gnueabi-. However, these toolchains target a generic Linux environment, and I'm not sure if they would be suitable for compiling a kernel for an Android device. I'm particularly concerned about potential optimization issues or compatibility problems that might arise from using these toolchains.
Questions:

Is it appropriate to use the generic Linux toolchains (*-linux-gnu-) for compiling an Android kernel?
What's the recommended approach to build the Android-specific toolchains (*-linux-android-) on an aarch64 host?

I am having difficulty finding answers on my own and would appreciate detailed explanations.
Environment:

Host: aarch64 (ARM64)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Target: Android phone (arm64)


You shouldn't need anything fancy to build android for aarch64 on aarch64. Just following the guide in the Android doc should suffice: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels
